# WebDriverWait not compiling with Selenium 3.3.1

Tags: java, selenium

Upgrading my framework to Selenium 3.3.1 I found one issue with WebDriverWait.  Any help would be appreciated. I've searched Selenium site and Stackoverflow for help.

```
functionX (WebDriver drvr, WebElement elem){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(drvr,3);
    wait.withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    wait.pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class); 


    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(elem));
}
```

The wait.until does not compile it gives the following error:

The method until(Function) in the type FluentWait is not applicable for the arguments (new ExpectedCondition(){})

Thank you for the support

Comment: how are you calling it?

Comment: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(elem));

Comment: No I meant functionX

Comment: What difference does that make.  the wait.until does not compile, I searched selenium and stack over flow. How do you call wait.until() in Selenium 3.3.1

Comment: I mean where do you call functionX() and what parametrs you are passing?

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'm passing in WebDriver,and WebElement. I don't understand why the wait.until does not compile. Look at my sample code above

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
 <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
 <version>21.0</version>
</dependency>
```